# Invalid interface:SandboxPostCopy

Tags: apex, visualforce, sandboxpostcopy

I am trying to create class that can be used post sandbox refresh and I am getting Invalid `Interface:SandboxPostCopy` error when trying to save.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
global class SandBoxPostCopy implements SandboxPostCopy  {
    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        insert new Account(name = 'Context Org Id: ' + context.organizationId() + 
                ' Context Sandbox Id: ' + context.sandboxId());
        insert new Account(name = ' UserInfo Session Id:  ' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + 
                ' UserInfo Org Id:  ' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
        insert new Account(name = ' Organization IsSandbox: ' + 
                [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization].IsSandbox);
    }
}
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice closely, name of your custom class and Salesforce interface are same; thus confusing the compiler.

> global class **SandBoxPostCopy** implements **SandboxPostCopy**

Rename your class appropriately to get rid of that error.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the Relpy. I changed the class name and still the same error.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add updated code with error?

Comment: Issue resolved. I logged out,  closed the browser and tried again and that worked.  Thanks Rahul.